# replacing ActionController::Routing::RouteSet::Mapper.send in Rails3 plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html and at
chapter 8, I'm told to add:
ActionController::Routing::RouteSet::Mapper.send :include,
Yaffle::Routing::MapperExtensions

In order to add the routes of my plugin in my Rails app...

Unfortunately, ActionController::Routing is deprecated in Rails 3 and I don't find anything to replace it in ActionDispatch,

What should I use instead?

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Keith Schacht code](http://keithschacht.com/creating-a-rails-3-engine-plugin-gem/) ! :)